# How to write SQL Select Query with a variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, sqlite

EDIT: now, I'm getting that my query statement has no results, when I know it does...

How to write a Select Statement in Swift that uses a local variable.

I have over 50 columns, how do I concatenate all the column names in an array?

```
let queryStatementStringSearch = "SELECT * FROM TABLE where Col1 = (?);"

var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
// 1
if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStatementStringSearch=, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    sqlite3_bind_text(queryStatement, 1, userInput, -1, nil)
    // 2
    if sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
        // 3
        let id = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)

        // 4
        let queryResultCol1 = sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 1)
        let name = String(cString: queryResultCol1!)

        // 5
        print("Query Result:")
        print("\(id) | \(name)")

    } else {
        print("Query returned no results")
    }
} else {
    print("SELECT statement could not be prepared")
}
```

Comment: I think you should follow the advice from @rmaddy when it comes to the format of your sql query as well. There is absolutely no need for parentheses and a ; at the end might cause issues to so remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your "SELECT" statement should be:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where Col1 = ?
```

Calls to `sqlite3_bind_xxx` expect a 1-based column number. You are passing an index of `2` but it needs to be `1`.

```
sqlite3_bind_text(queryStatement, 1, userInput, -1, nil)
```

Make sure you call `sqlite3_finalize` on the prepared statement.

It's also a bad idea to use `SELECT *`. Explicitly list the column names. This ensures that when you make calls to `sqlite3_column_xxx`, the index you pass (which is 0-based, not 1-based) is to a known column in a fixed position.